# how to change UITableViewCell from outside tableview methodes

Tags: uitableview, uiswitch

I have a UITableView that holds a UISwitch as a UITableViewCell accessoryView.[image]

I'm trying to create a method that responds to changes with the switches.
Basically there should be only one valve open on any given time so I want that when I turn a switch on, it will make the switch that is allready on to switch to off.

I did something like that:

```
-(IBAction)openCloseValve:(id)sender
```

{

```
UISwitch *theSwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;

if ([theSwitch isOn])

{

    //Open Valve!

    NSLog(@"Opening Valve!");

    Storage *strg = [Storage sharedStorage];

    

    UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:strg.openValve.intValue-1 inSection:0]];

    UISwitch *newSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    newSwitch.onTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    newSwitch.on = NO;

    oldCell.accessoryView = newSwitch;

    
    strg.openValve= [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:theSwitch.tag + 1];

    NSLog(@"%d", strg.openValve.intValue);

} else {

    //Close Valve!

    NSLog(@"Closing Valve!");

}
```

}

So far it does nothing.
I know the method is being called.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The old cell needs updating via [tableView reloadCellsAtIndexPath:]. You can avoid this by updating the old switch instead of creating a new one:

```
UISwitch *oldSwitch = (UISwitch *)oldCell.accessoryView;
oldSwitch.on = NO;
```

Comment: I allready tryied that but it's not working. I think that oldCell is not really getting the original cell becouse I tried to NSLog the cell's textLabel in order to verify exactly that and I get null. I must be missing something.

Comment: It seems that there is something wrong with the index path you're passing to the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Would you please NSLog the value of [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:strg.openValve.intValue-1 inSection:0] and make sure it's correct? BTW, have you thought of using the free Sensible TableView framework? I believe it makes performing tasks such as these very trivial. I've been using it for some time now and I can't imagine ever going back to doing things manually again.

Comment: <NSIndexPath 0x88aee70> 2 indexes [0, 3]